# Get address in popup on dragend

Tags: jquery, leaflet

I have a question regarding the dragend function with leaflet. I get latlng coordinates when dragging but I would like to get the address from the latlng coordinates on dragend. I have found this code already. Could someone please point me to the right direction?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

```
  var marker;
  var newPos;

  mymap.on('click', function(e) {

    geocodeService.reverse().latlng(e.latlng).run(function(error, result) {
      marker = new L.marker(result.latlng, {draggable:true,icon: greenIcon}).addTo(mymap).bindPopup(result.address.Match_addr).openPopup();
      marker.on('dragend', onDrag);
    });

    // Remove previous marker
    if (marker) {
      mymap.removeLayer(marker);
    }
  });


  // This is the dragend function:
var onDrag = function(e) {
  geocodeService.reverse().latlng(marker.getLatLng()).run(function(error, result) {
    marker.bindPopup(result.address.Match_addr).openPopup();
  });
};
```

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#geocoding

Comment: Thank you for the link.

I think I found a solution for my problem:

```
    var onDrag = function(e) {
        geocodeService.reverse().latlng(marker.getLatLng()).run(function(error, result) {
          marker.bindPopup(result.address.Match_addr).openPopup();
        });
    };